# How do I create this semi-enclosed arrow symbol?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I would like to create a symbol for `\implies` and `\impliedby` where they are enclosed in a rotated lidless box as shown in the picture. Can anybody tell me how I could achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome! You do not need any packages for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\RightArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}\begin{array}{@{}c@{}|}\hline 
\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\Rightarrow$}\\ \hline\end{array}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\LeftArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}\begin{array}{@{}c@{}|}\hline 
\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\Leftarrow$}\\ \hline\end{array}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
$\RightArrowInBox~\LeftArrowInBox$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can modify the padding etc.

A version without cutting corners with major input by barbara beeton.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\RightArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}\begin{array}{@{}c@{\rule[-3pt]{0.4pt}{0.85em}}}\hline 
\raisebox{-0.28ex}{$\Rightarrow$}\\ \hline\end{array}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\LeftArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}\begin{array}{@{}c@{\rule[-3pt]{0.4pt}{0.85em}}}\hline 
\raisebox{-0.28ex}{$\Leftarrow$}\\ \hline\end{array}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
$\RightArrowInBox~\LeftArrowInBox$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `trimclip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\RightArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\clipbox{0.5ex 0em 0em 0em}{\fbox{$\Rightarrow\!$}}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\LeftArrowInBox}{\begingroup
\clipbox{0.5ex 0em 0em 0em}{\fbox{$\Rightarrow\!$}}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
$\RightArrowInBox~\LeftArrowInBox$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The corners aren't closed.  Maybe add to the vertical two times the thickness of the rules.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! Yes, I know, we cats are famously good at cutting the corners. ;-)

Comment: Hmm.  Somehow, when adding corners, a little too much extra space got added below the arrows.  (Nit picking.)  The corners *do* look nice though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This is entirely controlled by the height of the rule. If the requirement is to make it symmetric, then you can either make the rule higher, or raise the box a bit lower, or a combination of those. For instance, `\raisebox{-0.275ex}{$\Rightarrow$}` leads to a very symmetric positioning. I just am not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution which places `\implies` and `\impliedby` into a modified version of `\fbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\@rframeb@x#1{%
  \@tempdima\fboxrule
  %\advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule
        \hbox{%
          %\vrule\@width\fboxrule
          #1%
          \vbox{%
            \vskip.7\fboxsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip.3\fboxsep}%
          #1%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule}%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule}%
                          }%
        }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\rfbox[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup
      \kern.2\fboxsep{#1}\kern.2\fboxsep
    \color@endgroup}%
  \@rframeb@x\relax}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\boximplies}{%
    \mathrel{\:\rfbox{$\Longrightarrow$}\:}%
}
\newcommand{\boximpliedby}{%
    \mathrel{\:\rfbox{$\Longleftarrow$}\:}%
}
\begin{document}
\( A \implies B \)

\( A \boximplies B \)

\( A \impliedby B \)

\( A \boximpliedby B \)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Only `array` (that's a required package in every distribution):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\bimplies}{\mathrel{\bimpl{c|}{\Rightarrow}}}
\newcommand{\bimpliedby}{\mathrel{\bimpl{|c}{\Leftarrow}}}
\newcommand{\bimpl}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{array}{#1}\hline{#2}\vphantom{+}\\\hline\end{array}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$A\bimplies B\bimpliedby C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this overlay of two symbols. Too bad there is no big square left/right, so it requires rotation.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\RightArrowInBox{%
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ooalign{%
  \hfil$\Downarrow$\hfil\cr\noalign{\kern0.4pt}%
  \hfil$\bigsqcup$\hfil\cr}}}
\newcommand\LeftArrowInBox{%
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\ooalign{%
  \hfil$\Downarrow$\hfil\cr\noalign{\kern0.4pt}%
  \hfil$\bigsqcup$\hfil\cr}}}
```

Other symbol collections like basic LaTeX or `stmaryrd` work better when inserting `\displaystyle` with the square or `\scriptstyle` with the arrow because the `\bigsqcup` is smaller than the version from `amssymb`.